# What is the difference of using separated web API instead of using a single MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

What is the difference of using separate **Web API** and Client instead of using a single **MVC** project in **C#**? As far as I know, by using separated **WEB API** other devices and Website can reuse the API and It's more safer and best practice than using a **MVC** project for both back end and front end.

Answer (score 0):

It can split better the data vs frontend. For example, there are db guru people who doesn't know frontend, and vice versa. Those parts can be implemented by same or different teams, or for example even different companies.